# Problem with backend request, after creating the building

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongodb, hosting

In short, during development, the backend worked normally, I could register, search for users, and so on. But when I created a build and sent it to hosting, I can't register and perform operations with the backend because an error appears. I will provide my code to understand the situation

Here is the error:
POST https://famfindtree.com:4000/register net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Here are the files: server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

const uri = "***";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

const User = client.db("FamfindTree").collection("users");

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username, email, password } = req.body;

        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (existingUser) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'User with this email already exists' });
        }

        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

        await User.insertOne({ username, email, password: hashedPassword });

        res.status(201).json({ message: 'User registered successfully' });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during registration:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
});

app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;

        const user = await User.findOne({ email });

        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid email or password' });
        }

        const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

        if (passwordMatch) {
            return res.status(200).json({ userId: user._id });
        } else {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid email or password' });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during login:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
});

app.post('/search', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username } = req.body;

        const searchQuery = {
            username: new RegExp(username, 'i'),
        };

        const results = await User.find(searchQuery).toArray();

        res.status(200).json(results);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during search:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
});

client.connect()
  .then(() => {
    const server = https.createServer({
      key: fs.readFileSync('./private_key.key'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl_ytetstggd.crt')
    }, app);

    server.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB:', error);
  });
```

register.jsx:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import '../styles/RegisterPage.css';

function RegisterPage() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        username: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
    });
    const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState({});

    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
    };

    const validateForm = () => {
        const errors = {};
        if (formData.username.trim() === '') {
            errors.username = 'Username is required';
        }
        if (formData.email.trim() === '') {
            errors.email = 'Email address is required';
        }
        if (formData.password.trim() === '') {
            errors.password = 'Password is required';
        }
        if (formData.confirmPassword !== formData.password) {
            errors.confirmPassword = 'Passwords do not match';
        }
        setFormErrors(errors);
        return Object.keys(errors).length === 0;
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const isFormValid = validateForm();

        const uuid = uuidv4();

if (isFormValid) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://famfindtree.com:4000/register', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ ...formData, uuid }), 
        });
        
        
            

        if (response.ok) {
            const responseData = await response.json();
            const userId = responseData.userId; 
            localStorage.setItem('authToken', userId);
            navigate('/');
        } else {
            const errorData = await response.json();
            console.error('Registration failed:', errorData.error);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during registration:', error);
    }
}
    };



    return (
        <div>
            <section>
                <div className='container-pc-ver'>
                    <div className='register-decorative-image'></div>
                    <div className='container-sign-up'>
                        <div className='register-content'>
                            <div className='logo-register'>
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="24" viewBox="0 0 25 24" fill="none">
                            <g clip-path="url(#clip0_3314_1044)">
                                <path d="M24.5 3.253C24.4818 4.4821 24.3727 5.70807 24.1736 6.92054C24.1304 7.20829 24.0776 7.49116 24.0248 7.76915C22.8664 6.93976 21.6241 6.23837 20.3192 5.6769C19.1422 5.16742 17.9187 4.77699 16.6664 4.51128C16.5875 4.48985 16.5073 4.47356 16.4264 4.46251C15.1622 4.20355 13.876 4.07124 12.5864 4.06747H12.4712C11.1816 4.07124 9.89541 4.20355 8.6312 4.46251C8.55026 4.47356 8.4701 4.48985 8.3912 4.51128C7.13888 4.77699 5.91537 5.16742 4.7384 5.6769C3.41518 6.23493 2.15509 6.93641 0.98 7.76915C0.9272 7.49116 0.8744 7.20829 0.8312 6.92054C0.630492 5.70819 0.51978 4.48222 0.5 3.253C1.69826 2.54789 2.95411 1.94905 4.2536 1.46312L4.5464 1.35582C5.71175 0.937102 6.90734 0.610984 8.1224 0.38041C8.3096 0.341394 8.5016 0.312132 8.6936 0.282869C9.84034 0.101731 10.9987 0.00718229 12.1592 0L12.8312 0C13.9922 0.0136361 15.1505 0.114706 16.2968 0.302378C16.4888 0.33164 16.6808 0.360902 16.868 0.399919C18.0831 0.630492 19.2787 0.95661 20.444 1.37533L20.7368 1.48263C22.0389 1.96177 23.298 2.55409 24.5 3.253Z" fill="#5757FF"/>
                                <path d="M19.3449 9.69055C18.9412 10.8435 18.4351 11.9568 17.8329 13.0167L17.6313 13.363C16.3554 12.7487 14.9819 12.3705 13.5753 12.2461C13.2181 12.2087 12.8592 12.1908 12.5001 12.1925C12.1401 12.1925 11.7801 12.1925 11.4249 12.2413C10.0164 12.3665 8.64118 12.7464 7.3641 13.363C7.98645 14.4119 8.70139 15.4011 9.5001 16.3185C9.6153 16.455 9.7353 16.5867 9.8553 16.7184C10.6639 17.6094 11.549 18.4255 12.5001 19.1569C13.6428 20.0275 14.8738 20.7714 16.1721 21.376C15.9849 21.5369 15.8025 21.693 15.6105 21.8637C14.6315 22.659 13.5914 23.3733 12.5001 23.9998C11.4077 23.3624 10.3675 22.6366 9.3897 21.8295C9.1977 21.6735 9.0153 21.5174 8.8281 21.3418C8.00072 20.6214 7.2214 19.8459 6.4953 19.0204C6.2649 18.757 6.0153 18.4888 5.8233 18.2156C5.18823 17.4193 4.60461 16.5819 4.0761 15.7088C3.8697 15.3772 3.6729 15.0358 3.4857 14.6895C3.00373 13.8034 2.57573 12.888 2.2041 11.9486C4.28551 10.1687 6.78072 8.95986 9.4521 8.43715C10.0642 8.31515 10.6829 8.23046 11.3049 8.18354C11.6985 8.15428 12.0969 8.13965 12.4953 8.13965C12.8937 8.13965 13.2921 8.13965 13.6857 8.18354C15.6471 8.33551 17.5649 8.8495 19.3449 9.70031V9.69055Z" fill="#5757FF"/>
                            </g>
                            <defs>
                                <clipPath id="clip0_3314_1044">
                                <rect width="24" height="24" fill="white" transform="translate(0.5)"/>
                                </clipPath>
                            </defs>
                        </svg>
                            </div>
                            <div className='container-title-register'>
                                <h1 className='title-register'>Create an account</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div className='container-register-txt'>
                                <p className='register-txt'>Let’s get started with your 30-day free trial.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className='container-register-form'>
                                <form
                                    id="registrationForm"
                                    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                                    action="/register"
                                    method='POST'
                                    className='register-form'
                                >
                                    <label htmlFor="username" className='register-label'>Login</label>
                                    <br />
                                    <input
                                        type="text"
                                        className='register-inputs'
                                        id="username"
                                        name="username"
                                        placeholder='Enter Login'
                                        required
                                        value={formData.username}
                                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                                    />
                                    {formErrors.username && <p className="error-message">{formErrors.username}</p>}
                                    <br />
                                    <label htmlFor="email" className='register-label'>Email address</label>
                                    <br />
                                    <input
                                        type="email"
                                        className='register-inputs'
                                        id="email"
                                        name="email"
                                        placeholder='Enter Email'
                                        required
                                        value={formData.email}
                                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                                    />
                                    {formErrors.email && <p className="error-message">{formErrors.email}</p>}
                                    <br />
                                    <label htmlFor="password" className='register-label'>Password</label>
                                    <br />
                                    <input
                                        type="password"
                                        className='register-inputs'
                                        id="password"
                                        name="password"
                                        placeholder='Enter Password'
                                        required
                                        value={formData.password}
                                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                                    />
                                    {formErrors.password && <p className="error-message">{formErrors.password}</p>}
                                    <br />
                                    <label htmlFor="confirm-password" className='register-label'>Repeat Password</label>
                                    <br />
                                    <input
                                        type="password"
                                        className='register-inputs'
                                        id="confirm-password"
                                        name="confirmPassword"
                                        placeholder='Repeat Password'
                                        required
                                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                                    />
                                    {formErrors.confirmPassword && <p className="error-message">{formErrors.confirmPassword}</p>}
                                    <br />
                                    <button type="submit" className='register-btn'>Create Account</button>
                                </form>
                                <div className='container-register-txt'>
                                    <p className='register-txt-login'>
                                        Already have an account?
                                        <Link to="/sign-in" className='register-link-to-login'>Log in</Link>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    );
}

export default RegisterPage;
```

Comment: I think there could be two issues. Either you are not using the Live Database (MongoDB deployed database) or you are using MongoDB live database for free. The free storage of MongoDB is for local development purpose and do not work if you use the free storage in production. That is why await User.findOne({ email }) do not get any response, your code does not move further, and you get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

Comment: @MuneebKhan Yes, you are right! I use the free version. Thank you!